# Type casting using string of type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have fully qualified class name which I have to use for type casting.
I can get type using

```
someType=Type.GetType("TypeName").
```

After Deserializing I am getting object which I have to typecast into particular type i.e TypeName.

I tried

```
obj = (someType) SXmlSerializer.Deserialize("TypeName", someData);
```

but that doesn't works .
Is there any option available to do typecasting using only class name as string?

I have to convert it into **someType** because I have to modify value for property i.e. `obj.SomeProperty = "AnotherValue"`.

Comment: If you know the type of the object that is going to be deserialized at compile time can you not cast to this type and avoid reflecting it?

Comment: Sorry I don't know the type of object at compile time, as there are possibility of having any type out of about 30-35 types

Comment: There is really no value doing exactly what you are asking as you can't specify type for `obj` at run time... Consider updating question with information *why* you think you need such code.

Comment: have you considered generics? if you're looking into reflection for dynamically casting objects based on string values, you know you need to take a long hard look at where you are and where you're going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to convert it into someType because I have to modify value for property i.e. obj.SomeProperty = "AnotherValue".

But if you don't know the type at compile time, how do you know it has a `SomeProperty` property?

If you want to *assume* that it does and defer type-checking to runtime then you could use `dynamic`:

```
dynamic obj = SXmlSerializer.Deserialize("TypeName", someData);
```

then you can do

```
obj.SomeProperty = "AnotherValue";
```

Which will fail at runtime if the object does not have a `SomeProperty` property.

Casting only affects how methods are bound at compile-time.  There's no value in casting if you don't know the type at compile-time.